# MySQL/MariaDB won't start

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, mariadb

I recently updated mariadb on my server from the debian repository and now the sql server won't start. I think there could be a conflict with old packages as a result of the update, but am not sure how to proceed. Here is the feedback from the system status of the sql server:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.15 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2019-05-22 15:08:27 UTC; 1min 12s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
 Main PID: 1328 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 22 15:08:25 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:25 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
May 22 15:08:25 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
May 22 15:08:25 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
May 22 15:08:25 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
May 22 15:08:25 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:25 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190522 15:08:25
May 22 15:08:27 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1989836; transaction id 536
May 22 15:08:27 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
May 22 15:08:27 enoki mysqld[1328]: 2019-05-22 15:08:27 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
May 22 15:08:27 enoki systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
May 22 15:08:27 enoki systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.15 database server.
```

I tried to repair it by treating it as a broken install and got the following message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client-10.1 : Conflicts: mysql-client-core-5.5
                       Conflicts: mysql-client-core-5.6
                       Conflicts: mysql-client-core-5.7
                       Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.5
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.6
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.7
 mariadb-client-10.3 : Conflicts: mariadb-client-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client
 mariadb-client-core-10.1 : Conflicts: mysql-client-5.5
                            Conflicts: mysql-client-5.6
                            Conflicts: mysql-client-5.7
                            Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client-core
                            Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.5
                            Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.6
                            Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.7
 mariadb-client-core-10.3 : Conflicts: mariadb-client-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
                            Conflicts: mariadb-client-core-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
                            Conflicts: virtual-mysql-client-core
 mariadb-plugin-mroonga : Breaks: mariadb-server-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 mariadb-plugin-spider : Breaks: mariadb-server-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 mariadb-plugin-tokudb : Breaks: mariadb-server-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 mariadb-server-10.1 : Conflicts: mysql-server-core-5.5
                       Conflicts: mysql-server-core-5.6
                       Conflicts: mysql-server-core-5.7
                       Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server
                       Breaks: mysql-client-5.5
 mariadb-server-10.3 : Conflicts: mariadb-server-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
                       Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server
 mariadb-server-core-10.1 : Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server-core
                            Breaks: mysql-client-5.5
                            Breaks: mysql-client-5.6
                            Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.5
                            Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.6
                            Breaks: mysql-server-core-5.7
 mariadb-server-core-10.3 : Conflicts: mariadb-server-core-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
                            Conflicts: virtual-mysql-server-core
                            Breaks: mariadb-client-10.1 but 1:10.1.38-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

The mysql error when I try to connect is:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

MySQL error log when I try to run it:

```
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.15 started; log sequence number 1989836; transaction id 535
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190522 22:32:35
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeded
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2019-05-22 22:32:35 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.15-MariaDB-1:10.3.15+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2019-05-22 22:34:05 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2019-05-22 22:34:05 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-05-22 22:34:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-05-22 22:34:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-05-22 22:34:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-05-22 22:34:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190522 22:34:05
2019-05-22 22:34:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1989845; transaction id 536
2019-05-22 22:34:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-05-22 22:34:06 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Output of "journalctl -xe":

```
May 22 23:09:26 enoki kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:28:c6:8e:26:6e:ee:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=58892 PROTO=2 
May 22 23:09:33 enoki systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
May 22 23:09:33 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:33 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566573.276:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:33 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:33 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566573.296:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:33 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:33 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566573.400:60): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:33 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:33 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566573.496:61): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:33 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:33 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566573.600:62): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:33 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:33 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566573.700:63): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:33 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:33 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566573.728:64): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:34 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:34 enoki audit[12157]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
May 22 23:09:34 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566574.308:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:34 enoki kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1558566574.308:66): apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=12157 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask
May 22 23:09:34 enoki systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
May 22 23:09:34 enoki systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.15 database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's in the MySQL error log?  By default, it's a file that ends with `.err` in the MySQL data directory.  If it's not there, the path may have been configured in your `/etc/my.cnf` or inside `/etc/my.cnf.d` as the `log-error` option.

Comment: I added the error log output to the original post.

Comment: Hm, looks like a graceful shutdown.  Are there any clues from `journalctl` or `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: I added the journalctl output. Same error is coming up in the syslog.

Comment: Do you have backups of your database? I would recommend that you simply nuke whatever installs you have on that server and just restore the databases.

Comment: I don't, I was hoping there would be a way to save them.

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [Why does mariadb keep dying? How do I stop it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/750604/18979) on Ask Ubuntu